# How to update value at Mongo DB?

Tags: java, mongodb, crud

I have to write DAO layer for Mongo DB.

I found that this isn't so easy.

My implementation is straightforward:

> delete document with the same key => and save updated it again

How possible to do it for List of elements?

For example JSON representation is next:

```
  "airItinerary" : {
    "originDestinationOptions" : {
      "originDestinationOption" : [ {
        "flightSegment" : [ {
          "departureAirport" : {
            "locationCode" : "DUB",
            "codeContext" : "IATA"
          },
          "arrivalAirport" : {
            "locationCode" : "CDG",
            "codeContext" : "IATA"
          },
```

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void update(MODEL model) {
    try {
        Field keyField1 = getKeyField(model);
        String fieldValue = getKeyFieldValue(keyField1, model);
        BasicDBObject query = createQuery(keyField1.getName(), fieldValue);
        DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
        if (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject dbObject = getDbObject(model);
            dbCollection.update(query, dbObject);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Data status %s isn't presented at %s with value %s", keyField1.getName(), dbCollection.getFullName(), fieldValue));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.getInstance().log(e.getCause());
    }
}

private Field getKeyField(MODEL model) {
    Field keyField = null;
    for (Field field : model.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(KeyField.class)) {
            keyField = field;
        }
    }
    if (keyField == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Couldn't find KeyField annotation at class '%s'", model.getClass().getName()));
    }
    return keyField;
}

private String getKeyFieldValue(Field keyField, Object model) {
    String result = null;
    try {
        if(keyField.isAnnotationPresent(KeyField.class)) {
            keyField.setAccessible(true);
            result = keyField.get(model).toString();
        }
        if(result == null || result.equals("")) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("KeyField property is empty");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Couldn't find KeyField annotation at class '%s'", model.getClass().getName()));
    }
    return result;
}

private BasicDBObject createQuery(String key, String value) {
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put(key, value);
    return query;
}
```

For shure should exist much better way for this result.

I can't find smt at mongo doc for achieving this result.

***How to achive the same effect with Mongo tools.***

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed to update directly; don't need to find as the first step and this will probably cause inconsistency between **update** and **find** operation.

```
@Override
public void update(MODEL model) {
    try {
        Field keyField1 = getKeyField(model);
        String fieldValue = getKeyFieldValue(keyField1, model);
        BasicDBObject query = createQuery(keyField1.getName(), fieldValue);

        DBObject dbObject = getDbObject(model);
        dbCollection.update(query, dbObject);

    /*  DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
        if (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject dbObject = getDbObject(model);
            dbCollection.update(query, dbObject);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Data status %s isn't presented at %s with value %s", keyField1.getName(), dbCollection.getFullName(), fieldValue));
        }
    */
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.getInstance().log(e.getCause());
    }
}

private Field getKeyField(MODEL model) {
    Field keyField = null;
    for (Field field : model.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(KeyField.class)) {
            keyField = field;
            break;  // add a break to jump out quickly.
        }
    }
    if (keyField == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Couldn't find KeyField annotation at class '%s'", model.getClass().getName()));
    }
    return keyField;
}
```

Also, `spring-data-mongodb` is a choice to handle these kind of issues.